# Get variable of Class inside onclick function

Tags: javascript

I'm getting a problem where I cannot access the national variables of a Class inside the `onclick` function of another variable of the same Class. I have made a small demo where I assign a message and return a `button` which should show the message, but it keeps printing `undefined` because it can't find the variable. Please Help

```js
class class1 {
  message = "";
  clicker = document.createElement("button");
  
  constructor(sentence) {
    this.message = sentence;
    this.clicker.id = "clicker";
    this.clicker.innerHTML = "CLICK ME";
    this.clicker.addEventListener("click", (function () {
        console.log(this.message);
    }).bind(this))
    return this.clicker;
  }
}

document.getElementById("content").appendChild(new class1("hello"));
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='content'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is bound with the HTML element who triggered the event, you can either use arrow functions or bind the desired specific lexical context.

Using arrow functions.

```js
class class1 {
  message = "";
  clicker = document.createElement("button");
  
  constructor(sentence) {
    this.message = sentence;
    this.clicker.id = "clicker";
    this.clicker.innerHTML = "CLICK ME";
    this.clicker.onclick = () => {
      console.log(this.message);
    }
    return this.clicker;
  }
}

document.getElementById("content").appendChild(new class1("hello"));
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='content'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Binding

```js
class class1 {
  message = "";
  clicker = document.createElement("button");
  
  constructor(sentence) {
    this.message = sentence;
    this.clicker.id = "clicker";
    this.clicker.innerHTML = "CLICK ME";
    this.clicker.onclick = (function() {
      console.log(this.message);
    }).bind(this)
    return this.clicker;
  }
}

document.getElementById("content").appendChild(new class1("hello"));
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='content'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how will you write this in the form of `this.clicker.addEventListener("click", funtion(){});`

Comment: I updated the snippet in my question, and I'm getting an error